# Make unavailable to choose some values of CHOICES in admin and custom form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

In my model I have next fields:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')
    ***Other fields here***


class Membership (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        ('manager', 'Manager'),
        ('developer', 'Developer'),
        ('business_analyst', 'Business analyst'),
        ('system_analysts', 'System analysts'),
    )

    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_CHOICES,)
```

I have 2 question.

1) How in admin page make some values of 'ROLE_CHOICES' in 'role' field unavailable. For example admin can can choose only manager or developer.

2) How to make the same behavior in the form? In custom form make available to select only a few values of 'role' field. Lets say 'developer' and 'business_analyst'?

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django choicefield filter in admin panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706965/django-choicefield-filter-in-admin-panel)

Comment: @Apero in this post additionally the author wants to show one more entry in choice so this is not what I want. In my case I want to block some values of choice. Do you have any ideas?